# What is parent Component for in JFolderChooser.showOpenDialog

Tags: java, components, parent, jfilechooser

Case 1:

```
JFileChooser myFileChooser;
myFileChooser.showOpenDialog(this); //this = parent Component
```

Case 2:

```
JFileChooser myFileChooser;
myFileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
```

What is the practical difference between the two cases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Checkout the Javadoc for JFileChooser

> The parent argument determines two
>   things: the frame on which the open
>   dialog depends and the component whose
>   position the look and feel should
>   consider when placing the dialog. If
>   the parent is a Frame object (such as
>   a JFrame) then the dialog depends on
>   the frame and the look and feel
>   positions the dialog relative to the
>   frame (for example, centered over the
>   frame). If the parent is a component,
>   then the dialog depends on the frame
>   containing the component, and is
>   positioned relative to the component
>   (for example, centered over the
>   component). If the **parent is null**,
>   then the dialog depends on no visible
>   window, and it's placed in a
>   look-and-feel-dependent position such
>   as the center of the screen.

internally it tries to get a window using the parent using this `JOptionPane.getWindowForComponent(parent)`. Which in turn checks if parent is null or not...

```
if (parentComponent == null)
    return getRootFrame();
```

If it is null then Root level frame is returned as parent container. 
Using the internal `SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame()`. The javadoc for `SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame()` says...

> Returns a toolkit-private, shared,
>   invisible Frame to be the owner for
>   JDialogs and JWindows created with
>   null owners.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the parent to determine which component the dialog is related to. It will determine the position of your dialog (centered, relative to the parent). I also guess that the dialog will be modal, thus blocking the parent window.

If you specify null, the dialog shown won't belong to any component, and I guess it will be displayed either at the top left of the screen or at the center (the last being more likely to happen, I have not tested).

Hop this helps !